# Show decimal value upto nth places in c#

Tags: c#

I know we can display decimals up to certain no of places (if that no of places is fixed). For example, we can display up to 2 places using `String.Format`:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);
```

But our requirement is, we have to fetch no of decimal places from database and display the decimal value up to that place. For example:

```
int n=no of decimal places
```

I want to write something like:

```
String.Format("{0:0.n}", 123.4567);
```

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Added Note: `String.Format` rounds off the digit. I am looking for something to omit the remaining digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
int n = 3;
string format = String.Format("{{0:0.{0}}}", new string('0', n));
Console.Write(String.Format(format, 123.4567)); // 123,457
```

as method:

```
public static string FormatNumber(double d, int decimalPlaces)
{
    string format = String.Format("{{0:0.{0}}}", new string('0', decimalPlaces));
    return String.Format(format, d);
}
```

or even simpler, using `ToString` + [`N` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx#NFormatString):

```
public static string FormatNumber(double d, int decimalPlaces)
{
    return d.ToString("N" + decimalPlaces); 
}
```

---

if you don't want the default rounding behaviour but you just want to truncate the remaining decimal places:

```
public static string FormatNumberNoRounding(double d, int decimalPlaces)
{
    double factor = Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    double truncated = Math.Floor(d * factor) / factor;
    return truncated.ToString();
}
```

Comment: As usual...You are Great :)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer less string formatting, this is perhaps simpler:

```
decimal d = 123.4567
Console.Write("rounded: {0}", decimial.Round(d, 3));
```

Additionally, you can control the type of rounding used:

```
decimial.Round(d, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Since not many people realise that .NET's default rounding method is ToEven, which rounds to the nearest even number. So values like 2.5 actually round to 2, not 3.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to round off. It would be great if I can do it without rounding the digits off?

Comment: How can you avoid that if the number of decimal places fetched from the database is less than the number of decimal places in the value? Your only options are rounding or truncation.

Comment: Truncate does the job. Thanks for suggestion.